# Why is moment js not working in mounted vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, momentjs, vue-component, vuex

When I put moment on the method like this:

```
<template> 
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        ...
        methods:{
            ...
            add(event){
                let current = moment()                  
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and then call the add method, it works without error.

But if I put moment on the mounted like this:

```
mounted(){
   let currentAt = moment()   
}
```

it does not work. It returns the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: moment is not
>   defined"

How can I solve this?

Comment: Show the HTML where you include your script tags.

Answer (score 12):

Since you are using `.vue` files, I am assuming you are using the vue-loader or some other loader within the webpack ecosystem. If you are, then you can do something like the following:

```
<script>
 export default{
    import moment from 'moment'
    ...
    methods:{
        ...
        add(event){
            let current = moment()                  
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Then, just make sure you either execute `yarn add moment` or `npm i -s moment`.

Comment: I think `import moment from 'moment'` needs to be before the `export default{`

Answer (score 4):

If you make a bundle, at the beginning of `script`, you need to `import moment from 'moment'`.

If you import the files in your HTML, put a script tag in the HTML:
`<script src="moment.js"></script>`.